# Ticketing number system using ID (or not)

Tags: infopath

I have a SharePoint list I need to create a column to be used as ticketing system.  I was thinking a simple text + ID column.  The field can be hidden, the users do not need to see it.  This will be for reporting only when they export to excel.

I know the ID only generates after submission so how can I still get the text + ID and what is the concat formula for it?  Thank you.

Comment: You should just be able to do something like `=CONCATENATE([My Text Field], " - ", ID)` in a calculated column. However, the ID column is already a unique, incremental number, to the list. Do you really need to concatenate anything to it?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use ID column in calculated formula. Workaround would be to run a workflow after item added and inside the workflow concatenate and update the field ticket id.